# Vulkan Validation Layers on Ubuntu 20

Tags: vulkan

I'm running this tutorial:

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers

I've got the code written, but after I compile my app I run it and get:

```
validation layers requested, but not available!
```

I'm using the Makefile provided by the https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment page and it outputs this:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -o VulkanTest main.cpp -lglfw -lvulkan -ldl -lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi
```

vulkaninfo says the layers are there:

```
VK_LAYER_INTEL_nullhw (INTEL NULL HW) Vulkan version 1.1.73, layer version 1:
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation (Khronos Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.2.131, layer version 1:
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation (LunarG Standard Validation) Vulkan version 1.2.131, layer version 1:
VK_LAYER_MESA_device_select (Linux device selection layer) Vulkan version 1.2.73, layer version 1:
VK_LAYER_MESA_overlay (Mesa Overlay layer) Vulkan version 1.1.73, layer version 1:
VK_LAYER_NV_optimus (NVIDIA Optimus layer) Vulkan version 1.2.175, layer version 1:
```

I feel like I should have at some point updated my Makefile/g++ command to link in/enable the validation layers in my binary executable, but I can't find the steps.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with a NVIDIA GPU.

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.2.131 is very old. Update your SDK.

I think this is an old version of Loader that showed the metalayers even if layers are not present. Real SDK [would show more layers](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.182.0/linux/getting_started.html#user-content-vulkan-sdk-layers-list). So either you do not really have SDK installed, or you are using the portable version and have not run `source ./setup_env.sh` for the terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

Try setup the validation layers.

```
sudo apt install vulkan-validationlayers-dev spirv-tools
```

[see tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment)